# Speed up layered navigation filter in Magento

Tags: layered-navigation, performance, ajax, filtered-nav

Any way to speed up the layered navigation?  I'm using a Manapro Filtered Navigation extension for some extra features, but it still takes about 5-6 seconds when I change each filter.

I only have 5 visible filters, so hopefully it's not that.  There are about 65k variations of products, so I don't know if it's just that, and maybe I need to look into speeding the mySQL queries somehow?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

For each attribute you have in Magento and that is marked as filtrable, it will make a call to getAllOptions() of attribute source model. Even if there is no filter results for it, it will invoke attribute option collection load. Possible solution other optimization tips described here:

http://www.slideshare.net/mobile/ivanchepurnyi/making-magento-flying-like-a-rocket-a-set-of-valuable-tips-for-developers

Also make sure the layered navigation block is cached ( many simple extensions just skip this)

Try solr based layered navigation as well.

Server performance is also important.

Comment: Where do I make sure the layered navigation block is cached?  Is it in cache management settings?

Comment: Is it "Blocks HTML output" part of the cache?

Comment: You need to debug this, to see if it works, not just enable.

Comment: ok thanks.  One other question. I'm trying to extend the `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Table` per your link, but I don't know how to exactly set up the config file for it so that Magento reads the new class. http://i.imgur.com/cIWRx5F.png

Comment: Please search for "magento rewrite classes". You can either create your new module or do all modifications in /local/Mage/